# verb + as close(ly?) as possible

Tags: verbs, adverbs

Consider the following sentences:

> I steer my vehicle as close as possible to the right.

OR

> I steer my vehicle as closely as possible to the right.

The first sentence is my version (I am not a native speaker), the second version is the corrected version form an English native speaker. I understand why the correction was made, since the corrector asked herself "How do I want to steer the vehicle? As closely as possible". So "closely" is the adverb to "steer", which makes total sense.

However, I still feel like the first version sounds more natural. What if I ask "Where do I want to steer the vehicle to? As close as possible to the right."? Does that make a difference, or am I just kidding myself here?

Comment: I'd say that with ***steering*** before ***to the right***, you should be saying *as **far** as possible*. But it's *I **ride** my bicycle as **close** as possible to the **kerb***, and we wouldn't normally use ***closely*** in that context.

Comment: ...there are dozens of written instances of [*"as **close** as possible to the kerb"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+close+as+possible+to+the+kerb%22) in Google Books, but only ***one*** instance of [*"as **closely** as possible to the kerb"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+closely+as+possible+to+the+kerb%22) - and that one instance is from one André Bernand, who's not a native Anglophone anyway.

Comment: "Close" and "closely" are both valid adverbs. Using adjectives instead of adverbs is very common in dialect and non-standard forms of English, and for that reason there is a tendency to hypercorrect and avoid any adverb that looks like an adjective in formal English. A similar example is "fast" vs "quickly": both are adverbs, but some people incorrectly believe "fast" is not an adverb and wrongly reject "I drove fast" in favour of "I drove quickly".